# Running Java Native libraries on Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, java-native-interface

I am trying to run Gurobi optimizer on the local run of hadoop. Gurobi uses JNI. To test how to run it on hadoop I've written the following code.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
      GRBEnv env2 = new GRBEnv();
      env2.set(GRB.IntParam.OutputFlag, 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    int res = ToolRunner.run(conf, new GurobiTest(), args);
    System.exit(res);
}
```

Before using, Gurobi requires to set some environmental variables (where LD_LIBRARY_PATH points to Gurobi native library):

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/username/System/gurobi563/linux64/lib
export GRB_LICENSE_FILE=/home/username/gurobi.lic
```

When I package my project and run it using jvm

```
java -cp ./target/GurobiOnHadoop-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar mpi.de.test.GurobiTest
```

everything seems to work fine

But when I am trying to run it on hadoop

```
hadoop jar ./target/GurobiOnHadoop-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar mpi.de.test.GurobiTest -libjars ./target/GurobiOnHadoop-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

I get an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no GurobiJni56 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
    at gurobi.GurobiJni.<clinit>(GurobiJni.java:193)
    at gurobi.GRBEnv.<init>(GRBEnv.java:16)
    at gurobi.GRBEnv.<init>(GRBEnv.java:11)
    at mpi.de.test.GurobiTest.main(GurobiTest.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:197)
```

I've tried many different things. I've added **"-Djava.library.path=/home/username/System/gurobi563/linux64/lib"** to the hadoop running command. I've set required environmental variables in **hadoop-env.sh**. I try to load *.so files from the code level (using e.g. **ystem
        .load("/home/username/System/gurobi563/linux64/lib/libGurobiJni56.so");**). I've also tried to send those libraries to the hadoop distributed file system, load files from that place or point enviromental variables to that place.

I am using:

java version "1.7.0_60"

hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u6

Debian 7.5 wheezy

Comment: Its hard to tell what exactly is going on with the information provided.  First, if you are specifying a path or filename, you should be using System.loadLibrary not .load. If you use .load, you need to set java.library.path and the argument needs to be a library name without the lib prefix or file extension. Other things to check: Does the hadoop process have +r-x on /home/username/System/gurobi563/linux64/lib?  Did you specify JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the hadoop config?

Comment: JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH are set in hadoop-env.sh.
Files in /home/username/System/gurobi563/linux64/lib have -rwxrwxrwx permission. System.loadLibrary("libGurobiJni56") returns java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libGurobiJni56.so in java.library.path (even when I run java locally with  LD_LIBRARY_PATH set).

Comment: Either System.loadLibrary("/home/username/System/gurobi563/linux64/lib/libGurobiJni56.so") or  System.load("GurobiJni56");

Answer (score 0):

It had turn out that I set JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH in hadoop-env.sh incorrectly.